# Why Raid 1 don't improve read performance like Raid 0?

Tags: performance, raid, software-raid, raid-1, raid-0

It should be able to read the data across the 2 disks like with Raid 0 right?

but when I look at benchmark it looks like only one drive is used to read the data.

https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Performance

Comment: If both disks have the same information why do you want to read the 2 disks?

Comment: @CaldeiraG to get faster read speed. read half the data on each disk at the same time like in raid 0

Comment: Depends on the raid chip hardware and driver if it will support reading from both drives or not.

Comment: @Moab why the driver will not do that if it can be 2 times faster?